# Is there a way to run a custom model on the cloud with Firebase ML?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, firebase-mlkit

I am building an app for farmers where I want to run an image classification model. I have concluded that Google Firebase ML will be a good option for my app. However, the farmers' phones will not be very new and I don't think will be able to efficiently run large models. I have already built my model in Tensorflow and would like to run it on the cloud but I cannot find anything on this in the documentation. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Firebase ML does not support deploying Tensorflow models for running prediction in the cloud. However, Google Cloud does. Please take a look at [Deploying models](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/deploying-models) on the Cloud AI website.